# Unix cut command for empty string

Tags: string, unix, cut

I'm trying to use `cut -f` to get desired part of the following:

```
""
""
""HTTP/1.1""200""OK""
```

In order to get `HTTP/1.1`, I'll need to do:

```
cut -f 3,3 -d '"'
```

Result will be:

```
empty
empty
HTTP/1.1
```

So first two lines will be empty, (I use "empty" to indicate that)

But I would need to keep the empty string:

```
""
""
HTTP/1.1
```

I guess I need to introduce if-else, that if original line is empty then stop cut, just keep `""`? But how can I do this using one-line bash?

Thanks

=======
A followup question:
How to change

```
,,,
```

to

```
,"","",""
```

`s/^$/\"\"/g` does not work here.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the result of your `cut` command to:

```
sed s/^$/\"\"/g
```

It will replace the empty lines with `""`.

That is:

```
cut -f 3,3 -d '"' | sed s/^$/\"\"/g
```

Comment: Thanks! Works well...so ^$ indicates empty?

Comment: Yes, it *matches* an *empty line*.

Comment: Hi, can you help to look at my followup question (I edit my post)?  Thx

Comment: @user815408 Is not `sed s/,/,\"\"/g` what you want?

Comment: `^$` only matches *empty lines*.

Comment: sed s/,/,\"\"/g....works so cool...beautiful code....I'm such an idiot...Haven't worked with sed for a long time...Many thanks!